# 'had began’ vs. 'had begun'

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, grammaticality-in-context

In the short story "In the Eye of the Beholder" by Jeffrey Archer there's a sentence that goes:

> By the time Gian Lorenzo **had began** his apprenticeship, Paolo had been appointed captain of Roma.

Why is the phrase 'had began' correct in this sentence and exactly how is the phrase different from 'had begun'?

Comment: I think it is incorrect. It should be "had begun".

Comment: I too thought it was a typo. But it's Jeffrey Archer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an OCR error. Google Books has 25 instances of the cited text, 23 of which are correct *([**had begun**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22By+the+time+Gian+Lorenzo+had+begun%22))*, and only 2 have the erroneous [***had began***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22By+the+time+Gian+Lorenzo+had+began%22).

Comment: I hope it isn't closed as it is a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is ungrammatical. *Began* never takes an auxiliary verb, while *begun* always does. *Began* is the simple past of *begin* and *begun* is the past participle. You use *began* for an isolated action, and *begun* with an action alongside something else.

Both of these are correct:

> Paolo **was** appointed captain of Roma. Shortly afterwards, Gian Lorenzo **began** his apprenticeship.
>
> By the time Gian Lorenzo **had begun** his apprenticeship, Paolo **had been** appointed captain of Roma.

But you cannot mix the two as was done in the printing of the book.